# About the spiritual soul: can animals apprehend universals?

Tags: philosophy, souls, thomas-aquinas, animals, metaphysics

I'm struggling with this question for a while:

It seems like dogs do know what dogs are. Is it possible for a dog to only recognize individuals and not grasp the universal concept of dog?

I thought this ability to recognize universals was the ability that God gave to Adam (to name things) and thus that separated him from the animals.

How did the Christian scholastic theologians (such as St. Thomas Aquinas) separate the animal and spiritual capacities of human beings?

Comment: There is no support in scripture for the concept stated in paragraph three regarding 'recognize universals'. God made man a living soul, is what the scripture states.

Comment: @NigelJ yeah, but it is something I heard from the thomistics and I would like to hear their views on the topic

Comment: Welcome to C.SE. the question as you originally phrased it is borderline not suitable for this site and better posed to Philosophy.SE.  I made some change so it can potentially be accepted here as C.SE deals primarily with theology which in turn use philosophy.

Comment: @hellofriends Maybe dogs only *appear* to be able to do that in their brain like how today's AI does picture recognition (using a model from trained neural network) except it includes extra-visual senses like smell.  You are correct in attributing the true ability for humans to recognize universals from phantasms in our brain because of our distinctive rational soul.

Comment: "*Is it possible for a dog to only recognize individuals and not grasp the universal concept of dog?*" — Their primary sense is smell, so I don't think it takes much intelligence for them to recognize that all dogs have a common scent. A more meaningful criterion would be the ability to recognize oneself (e.g. in a mirror), and dogs can't do that. Only dolphins and a few higher primates have demonstrated this ability.

Comment: @RayButterworth yeah, there is the smell but many dogs smell different from each other and when a dog sees another, it knows exactly it is not a funny looking human nor a cat

Comment: @GratefulDisciple that cannot be the case for an AI is programmed by people who know the concepts beforehand, and a dog isn't. A dog is born, and it must recognize its mother without any kind of human programming. Induction alone cannot be the main method of learning

Comment: I would prefer that questions like this remain here.  Thomism may be on topic on Philosophy.SE, but you ought to get a better answer here.

Comment: @PeterTurner Agree with you about C.SE to answer.  This is a theological anthropology question and would possibly already been addressed by Aquinas in his *Summa* or in the *Summa Contra Gentiles*, although the answer needs to address findings in neuroscience & philosophy of mind.  The question can be tweaked even further if necessary.

Comment: @hellofriends I didn't imply that a dog learned universals like a neural network (through refinement of pattern recognition) but that there most likely be a limit to an animal's ability to abstract a concept out of sense perception.  A dog may be naturally bonded to its mother, as well to other dogs (for procreation), but I doubt it apprehends the concept of "mother" or "dog" which I don't think it necessary for a dog's "soul" to have, making that capacity remains at the level of instinct.  I even allow dogs to have immaterial souls (!), but in Thomism rational soul is a difference in kind.

Comment: I believe Adam naming the animals is more about demonstrating God given authority over them than 'recognizing universals'.

Comment: @MikeBorden that authority should be inprinted in our souls, don't you think?